# Picasso causing OutOfMemory error

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin, picasso

I'm using Picasso to load pictures into a grid, however each time I scroll down or up for it to load pictures, it fills up the heap so much that after 2-3 scrolls it runs out of memory. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using *******.Adapters;
using *******.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Com.Squareup.Picasso;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace *******.Fragments {
    public class Gallery : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment {
        private GridView gridView;
        private ISharedPreferences pref;
        private SessionManager session;
        private DeviceModel deviceModel;
        public static Activity activity;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private string cookie;
        private string sensorId;
        private List<string> photos;
        private const string URL_DATA = "http://*******/appapi/getdata";

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            activity = Activity;
            session = new SessionManager();
            pref = Activity.GetSharedPreferences("UserSession", FileCreationMode.Private);
            cookie = pref.GetString("PHPSESSID", string.Empty);
            sensorId = Arguments.GetString("id");
            photos = new List<string>();
        }

        public async override void OnStart() {
            base.OnStart();

            //          progressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(activity, String.Empty, GetString(Resource.String.loading_text));
            //          progressDialog.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DimBehind);

                        await GetSensorData();
                        await GetPhotoUrls();

            gridView.Adapter = new ImageAdapter(activity, photos);

            gridView.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) => {
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, e.Position.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };

            //          progressDialog.Hide();
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Gallery, container, false);

            gridView = view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview);

            return view;
        }

        public async Task GetSensorData() {
            var jsonFetcher = new JsonFetcher();
            JsonValue jsonGalerry = await jsonFetcher.FetchSensorDataAsync(URL_DATA, sensorId, "DESC", "20", cookie);
            deviceModel = new DeviceModel();
            deviceModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceModel>(jsonGalerry);
        }

        public async Task GetPhotoUrls() {
            foreach (var data in deviceModel.SensorData) {
                string url = "*******" + data.StringData;
                Console.WriteLine(url);
//              Bitmap photoBitmap = await new ImageDownloader().GetImageBitmapFromUrlAsync(url, Activity, 300, 300);
//              Drawable photoDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, photoBitmap);
                photos.Add(url);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ImageAdapter : BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        List<string> photos;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<string> photos) {
            this.context = context;
            this.photos = photos;
        }

        public override int Count {
            get { return photos.Count; }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
//              imageView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams (500, 500);
//              imageView.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
                //              imageView.SetPadding (8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }

            var imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
            imageDownloader.DownloadImage(photos[position], context, imageView);

            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

DownloadImage method:

```
    public void DownloadImage(string url, Context context, ImageView imageView) {
    var picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).Downloader(new PhotoDownloader(context)).Build();
    picasso.Load(url).Into(imageView);
}

private class PhotoDownloader : UrlConnectionDownloader {
    private Context context;

    public PhotoDownloader(Context context) : base(context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected override HttpURLConnection OpenConnection(Android.Net.Uri uri) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = base.OpenConnection(uri);
        ISharedPreferences pref = context.GetSharedPreferences("UserSession", FileCreationMode.Private);
        string cookie = pref.GetString("PHPSESSID", string.Empty);

        conn.SetRequestProperty("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=" + cookie);

        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like your calling picasso builder everytime right? Maybe you should juste build it once

Comment: Why do you create the ImageDownloader every time? I would also suggest to use the generic version of BaseAdapter  (BaseAdapter<T>). Your GetItemId returns always 0. A better implementation would be to return the position itself. I also assume that your ConvertView will always be a new instance of ImageView. This would explain to me why you are running out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [gropapa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658072/picasso-causing-outofmemory-error#comment55090427_33658072) is correct: If you build a new `Picasso` instance more than one, each of them will have a separate cache and your app will run out of memory very quickly.

Instead, I would build the instance only once (maybe in the `onCreate` of your `Application`) and then use `Picasso.setSingletonInstance` to store that instance for later usage. From that point on `Picasso.with` will always return the instance you created. Note that you *must* do that before the first call to `Picasso.with()` (because otherwise Picasso will create its own instance on the first call and will throw an Exception if you call `setSingletonInstance` later).